# Stanford core NLP models for English language

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am using stanford corenlp for a task. There are two models "**stanford-corenlp-3.6.0-models**" and "**stanford-english-corenlp-2016-01-10-models**" on stanford's website. I want to know what is the difference between these two models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the "Human languages supported" section of CoreNLP Overview , the basic distribution provides model files for the analysis of well-edited English,which is the stanford-corenlp-3.6.0-models you mentioned.

But,CoreNLP member also provides a jar that contains all of their English models, which includes various variant models, and in particular has one optimized for working with uncased English (e.g., mostly or all either uppercase or lowercase).The newest one is stanford-english-corenlp-2016-10-31-models and the  previous one is stanford-english-corenlp-2016-01-10-models you mentioned.

Reference:

http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/index.html#programming-languages-and-operating-systems

(the Stanford CoreNLP Overview page)

Comment: I find that I misunderstand the question before , so I try to get more materials to remedy that , thank you.@PetterFriberg

Comment: Yes basically stanford-corenlp-3.7.0-models.jar has some basic models to use the toolkit, whereas stanford-english-corenlp-2016-10-31-models.jar has ALL resources we have available for English.  The reason for the two different jars is that the English models jar is substantially larger and some people might want to download the large file.  If you don't mind the huge file size of the English models jar that is a better jar to use since it will have all resources for English.

Comment: Thanks for your response. it helped me understand the difference clearly.